# Django Rest Framework ordering by count of filtered pre-fetched related objects

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm hoping someone might be able to help me. I am working with Django Rest Framework, and attempting to create an API that allows users to search for `Provider`s that provide specific `Procedure`s in particular `Region`s, and only return the relevant details.

### Set up

I have these models (heavily simplified):

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator

class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]

class Procedure(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["description"]

class Provider(models.Model):
    provider_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["provider_name"]

class Provision(models.Model):
    fk_procedure = models.ForeignKey(
        Procedure,
        related_name="providers",
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
    )
    fk_provider = models.ForeignKey(
        Provider,
        related_name="services",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    discount = models.FloatField(
        validators=[MaxValueValidator(100), MinValueValidator(0)],
        default=0,
    )
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-discount"]
        unique_together = ["fk_procedure", "fk_provider"]

class ProvisionLinkRegion(models.Model):
    fk_provision = models.ForeignKey(
        Provision,
        related_name="regions",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    fk_region = models.ForeignKey(
        Region,
        related_name="services",
        on_delete=models.RESTRICT,
    )
    location = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

As you can see, there is a ManyToMany link between `Provision` and `Region` via `ProvisionLinkRegion`. I haven't defined this as a ManyToMany field though, as I need to store additional details (`location`) about the pairing.

I have defined the following serializers on these models:

```py
# serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from models import (
    Provider,
    Region,
    Procedure,
    ProvisionLinkRegion,
    Provision,
)

class ProvisionLinkRegionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ProvisionLinkRegion
        fields = ["fk_region", "location"]

class ProvisionDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    regions = ProvisionLinkRegionSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Provision
        fields = ["fk_procedure", "discount", "mff_opt_out", "regions"]

class ProviderProvisionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    services = ProvisionDetailsSerializer(many=True) 
    number_services = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = Provider
        fields = [
            "provider_name",
            "services",
            "number_services",
        ]
```

And have defined my API like this:

```py
# api.py

from django.db.models import Prefetch, Count
from rest_framework import generics, pagination, permissions, status
from rest_framework.response import Response

from serializers import ProviderProvisionSerializer
from models import (
    Provider,
    ProvisionLinkRegion,
    Provision,
)

class CustomPagination(pagination.PageNumberPagination):
    page_size_query_param = "limit"

    def get_paginated_response(self, data):
        return Response(
            {
                "pagination": {
                    "previous": self.get_previous_link(),
                    "next": self.get_next_link(),
                    "count": self.page.paginator.count,
                    "current_page": self.page.number,
                    "total_pages": self.page.paginator.num_pages,
                    "items_on_page": len(data),
                },
                "results": data,
            }
        )

class ProvisionListAPI(generics.ListAPIView):

    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = ProviderProvisionSerializer
    pagination_class = CustomPagination

    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = Provider.objects.distinct()

        # Extract the query parameters
        params = self.request.query_params
        region_list = params["region"].split(",")
        procedure_list = param["procedure"].split(",")

        # Build up the prefetch Provision table filtering on the regions
        # and services
        services_prefetch_qs = (
            Provision.objects.distinct()
            .filter(regions__fk_region__in=region_list)
            .filter(fk_procedure__in=procedure_list)
            .prefetch_related(
                Prefetch(
                    "regions",
                    queryset=ProvisionLinkRegion.objects.filter(
                        fk_region__in=region_list
                    ),
                )
            )
        )

        # Apply the filters and prefetch required tables
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            services__regions__fk_region__in=region_list
        ).prefetch_related(
            Prefetch("services", queryset=services_prefetch_qs),
        )

        # Add the ordering parameters
        queryset = (
            queryset.annotate(
                number_services=Count("services", distinct=True)  # FIXME
            )
            .filter(number_services__gt=0)
            .order_by("-number_services")
        )

        return queryset.all()

    def list(self, response):
        # Check it has the right headers
        params = self.request.query_params

        if "procedure" not in params:
            return Response(
                {"detail": "procedure not provided as a query parameter"},
                status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )
        if "region" not in params:
            return Response(
                {"detail": "region not provided as a query parameter"},
                status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )

        # Paginate and filter queryset
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

My problem is, the `number_services` value is not correct, as it's not doing the count on the full filtered results. It's only doing it on the pre-filtered ones (although the region filter does work). I also don't want any providers to appear when they don't have any services (hence the `.filter(number_services__gt=0)`).

I think that it's related to not filtering on the main `Provider` queryset like I do with the region i.e. to include:

```py
queryset = queryset.filter(services__fk_procedure__in=procedure_list)
```

But when I include this, it doesn't actually remove the services, but just the providers that don't provide ANY of those services, so the count is still off.

### Example

If my data with no filtering or prefetching looks like this:

```json
    "results": [
        {
            "provider_name": "Provider 2.0",
            "services": [
                {
                    "fk_procedure": 3,
                    "discount": 0.05,
                    "regions": [
                        {
                            "fk_region": 1,
                            "location": true
                        },
                        {
                            "fk_region": 2,
                            "location": false
                        }
                        {
                            "fk_region": 3,
                            "location": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "fk_procedure": 5,
                    "discount": 0.05,
                    "regions": [
                        {
                            "fk_region": 1,
                            "location": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "provider_name": "Test Provider",
            "services": [
                {
                    "fk_procedure": 2,
                    "discount": 0.00,
                    "regions": [
                        {
                            "fk_region": 1,
                            "location": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

If I then run this on it:

```
GET /api/v1/provision?page=1&limit=10&region=1,3&services=3`
```

I want to show all the providers and the relevant details where they relate to either region 1 or 3, and procedure 3.

#### Actual Result

```json
{
    "pagination": {
        "previous": null,
        "next": null,
        "count": 2,
        "current_page": 1,
        "total_pages": 1,
        "items_on_page": 2
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "provider_name": "Provider 2.0",
            "services": [
                {
                    "fk_procedure": 3,
                    "discount": 0.05,
                    "regions": [
                        {
                            "fk_region": 1,
                            "location": true
                        },
                        {
                            "fk_region": 3,
                            "location": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "number_services": 2
        },
        {
            "provider_name": "Test Provider",
            "services": [],
            "number_services": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Desired Result

```json
{
    "pagination": {
        "previous": null,
        "next": null,
        "count": 2,
        "current_page": 1,
        "total_pages": 1,
        "items_on_page": 2
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "provider_name": "Provider 2.0",
            "services": [
                {
                    "fk_procedure": 3,
                    "discount": 0.05,
                    "regions": [
                        {
                            "fk_region": 1,
                            "location": true
                        },
                        {
                            "fk_region": 3,
                            "location": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "number_services": 1,
        }
    ]
}
```

### Things I've tried

#### SerializerMethodField

I've been able to get `number_services` to work using a `SerializerMethodField` by including:

```py
# serializers.py

class ProviderProvisionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    number_services = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    ...
    class Meta:
        ...

    def get_number_services(self, obj):
        return obj.services.count()
```

Unfortunately though, I can't use this for ordering, or filtering within the API, and I also can't use it with pagination either, so is pretty useless for what I need it for.

#### Subquery

In the `get_queryset` method for the API, I've also tried using what I currently have as a subquery, and using the main queryset where the ID is in the other one, but then I lose all the prefetch from the first subquery, and have regions and services that don't relate to my filter.

## TLDR

How do I filter a queryset in a `get_queryset` method for a `ListAPIView` on properties of the children of the main model, and be able to return a count of the remaining children after the filter has taken place?